Why does System.console() return "java.io.ProxyingConsole@7ab2bfe1" when I think it should return null?
I'm trying to make a program that will open the command line for the user to interact with when you run it. I did some research on how to do this and found this solution on stack overflow which is basically what I need:
How do I make my java application open a console/terminal window?
It checks if the program has a console associated with it, and if not, launches the command line and runs the jar file from within it. All the solutions I've found use the same method of checking if System.console() is null to check if the program is running with a console such as:
Find out if Java program is running from CMD or not
How to check if application runs on the command line?
Here's the code I'm using that takes inspiration from the link above.
if(System.console() == null) {
    String filename = Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString().substring(6);
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd","/c","start","cmd","/k","java","-jar","\"" + filename + "\""});
    System.exit(0);
}

Unfortunately when I run the jar file nothing visibly happens. I tried modifying the program to open a command line window that displays what System.console() returns to make sure that it's null like I expect, but instead I get "java.io.ProxyingConsole@7ab2bfe1"
I tried looking up java.io.ProxyingConsole (and variations) and all I can find is the source code which doesn't help me much. I tried making my code more and more similar to the example and eventually just tried outright copy pasting it in to see if it would work but the problem persisted. From what I can tell System.console() will never return null.
Ways to disable this, detect if it's a "ProxyingConsole", or alternatives ways to detect if there is a console/run the program in cmd line from the jar are all appreciated

This question is similar to: Find out if Java program is running from CMD or not. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

System.console was probably supposed to be System.console(). The method will never be null, but the return value can be.

Always use ProcessBuilder with inheritIO() these days. No need to quote the last argument (jar path) if using an array

I modified the title to hopefully be more clear about how my issue differs from that question and included it as well as another question I thought might be considered similar to address how they don't answer my question. You're right System.console was supposed supposed to be System.console() but that was a typo on my part when I recreated the original code I ran before I modified it to experiment more with the problem. I can confirm that fixing that doesn't fix my issue.

What version of Java are you using? In Java 23 (or maybe 22 - I can't remember) System.console() no longer returns null.

I'm using 22 now but when I first encountered the issue I was using 17. I thought maybe updating it might fix the issue but it didn't. Am I best off using an older version?

Read the Java 22 release notes.  There is a section that explains what has changed ... and what to do rather than testing if console() returns null.

Stephen C's answer:
"Read the Java 22 release notes. There is a section that explains what has changed ... and what to do rather than testing if 'console()' returns 'null.'"
Helped me. He left it as a comment so I'm replying with an answer to make sure it's preserved and so people have to do less manual digging but the credit goes to him.
The JDK 22 release notes say that System.console() will no longer return null when the standard streams are redirected or connected to a virtual terminal. Instead the Console.isTerminal() method allows you to check if the console is connected to a terminal.
Console console = System.console();
if(!console.isTerminal()) {
    //code goes here...
}


Additionally running with -Djdk.console=java.base will restore the old functionality

It looks like System.console() is not behaving as expected in your environment, possibly because of how the JVM or IDE is configured. Sometimes, when running Java applications from IDEs or certain environments, System.console() may not return null even if the application isn't actually being run from a terminal.
Here’s an alternative approach to determine if your Java application is running in a terminal or not:
Using System.getenv() and System.getProperty()
You can use environment variables and system properties to infer whether your application is running in a terminal.

On Windows, the presence of the COMSPEC environment variable typically indicates a terminal or command prompt environment.
On Unix-like systems, the presence of the TERM environment variable suggests that the application might be running in a terminal.

private static boolean isRunningInTerminal() {
        // Check if environment variables typically set for terminals are present
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        if (os.contains("windows")) {
            String comSpec = System.getenv("COMSPEC");
            return comSpec != null && !comSpec.isEmpty();
        } else {
            String term = System.getenv("TERM");
            return term != null && !term.isEmpty();
        }
    }

You could also check for the presence of specific system properties or runtime configurations that are indicative of running in a terminal environment. add additional debugging outputs to understand the environment better:
System.out.println("Console: " + System.console());
System.out.println("COMSPEC: " + System.getenv("COMSPEC"));
System.out.println("TERM: " + System.getenv("TERM"));
System.out.println("OS Name: " + System.getProperty("os.name"));
System.out.println("OS Version: " + System.getProperty("os.version"));
System.out.println("Java Version: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
System.out.println("User Directory: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
System.out.println("Current Working Directory: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));

This will help you determine what environment variables and properties are available, and why System.console() might not be returning null.

These things are not entirely reliable.  For a start, environment variables can be changed by the user.  For seconds ... on UNIX / Linux, the TERM variable will be agnostic as to whether standard input / output / error has been redirected. So you are back where you started: not knowing if you can actually get input from the user.

to run a program from your OS, you can use the following lines:
A) you want that at the end of the execution, your application continue:
public void executeProgram() {
   try {
      Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
      runtime.exec( "cmd" ); 
      runtime.runFinalization();
   }
   catch( IOException e ) {
      e.getCause();
   } 
}

B) you want that at the end of execution, your application will close:
public void executeProgram() {
   try {
      Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
      Process process = runtime.exec( "konsole" );
      process.waitFor();
      runtime.runFinalization();
   }
   catch( IOException e ) {
      e.getCause();
   }
   catch( InterruptedException e ) {
      e.getCause();
   }
}

Note: I don't know about Windows, but on Linux, the command (“cmd”) must be lowercase.
